# How can i make a strncpy function?

Tags: c, string

i want to make a strncpy function so i try to make it but i can't.

i made a struct. struct have int age ; and char name[20]. so  i want to name[20] copy strings which from scanf. but it fail... how can i make a 
strlcpy function?

```
  (*list).name++ = name++;
```

is error... if this is work, i can make a strncpy.

```
void makeUserList (Unit* list, const char *name, int age ){
    while (*name) {

        NSLog(@"%c",*name);
        (*list).name++ = name++;
//       (list->name)++ = name++;

        NSLog(@"%c",*list[roomNum].name);

    }
```

i'm from korea. please understand my english grammar... 
Have a nice daY~

Comment: What are the requirements of a `strlcpy` function?  Your title says `strncpy`.

Comment: oh sorry i will fix it

Comment: thanks ~ for giving me a advice

Comment: `(*list).name++ = name++;` should be `*((*list).name++) = *(name++);` shouldn't it?

Comment: oh it didn't work . but thanks~

Comment: Xcode said that it can't not increment value of char[]..

Comment: Might want to read through ["The C Programming Language"](http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf). It covers these sorts of problems (ie. looping through data via pointers) at the fundamental C level.

Comment: what's mean that? Xcode can cover all c language?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code `(*list).name++ = name++;` will copy only one character. It should be repeated for the whole length of `name`. Second: This code will modify the `list`'s `name` field as well, such that it will point to the end of the copied string, which is obviously not what you want. If you want this to work, you should copy the destination pointer and work with this copy. Look [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strncpy.c) for example.

Comment: i got the fundamentals of this function. so i try (*list).name++ = name++; this code... but it fail.. so i want to fix that code...

Comment: You want to copy a string, i guess.

Comment: yes i want to copy a string... this problem made me crazy during 5days...:)